# Передать данные из input в файл *.gs

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Добрый день.

Есть файл application.gs

```
function doGet(e) {
var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('test');
return template.evaluate();
}
```

И файл test.html

```
 <div>
 <form id='theForm'>
 <input type='text' id='name' required>Введите имя</input>
 </form>
 </div>
```

Если добавить в форму

```
<button>Отправить</button>
```

то GET запрос не ловится функцией doGet()

Подскажите, как можно получить данные введённые в input в файле *.gs, чтобы потом их внести в google spreadsheets.

Comment: Чтобы что-то ловилось doGet(e), скрипт нужно опубликовать как веб приложение. И тогда на его адрес можете отправлять как Get запрос, так и Post

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но скрипт опубликован, как веб приложение. Собственно, поэтому и возник вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Основной технологией клиент-серверного взаимодействия в Google Apps Script Web Apps является т.н. [Client-side API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

#### Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}

function doSomething() {
  Logger.log('I was called!');
}
```

#### Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      google.script.run.doSomething();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Если же вы намерены отправлять именно формы, то необходимо позаботится о том, чтобы скрипт отвечал на GET/POST запросы

```
function doGet(e){
  if(!e)
    return HtmlService;
  return ContentService;
}

function doPost(e){
  return ContentService;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

doGet(e) начал корректно ловить запрос после явного указания атрибута formaction в тэге .

Comment: Лучше бы немного поподробнее.

Comment: Какая-то фантастика.